# Display *user-added* local image using SQLite to store file location

Tags: react-native, sqlite

I'm aware that one can't load local images dynamically in React-Native. However, I know I can require all the images at App load-time then dynamically choose which one do display by running something like the following:

```
export function loadImportedImages(imageName) {
  const importedImages = [
    {
      name: 'image1',
      image: require('../../assets/images/image1.jpg')
    }
  ];

  const foundImage = importedImages.filter((img) => img["name"] === imageName);
  return foundImage[0].image;
};
```

However, I need to go one step further but I can't figure it out.

I would like to allow users to add images to the app, storing the appropriate image name, location, etc. in the SQLite database. From there, I would like to be able to load those user-uploaded images into the App.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Even if I can dynamically create the `importedImages` array using information from the database, the problem of the `require()` function would remain as the variable passed to it would still be dynamically-determined, not static.

One thought would be to simply create a large number of Objects inside `importedImages` that contain something like:

```
const importedImages = [
  {
    name: 'image1',
    image: require('path-to-placeholder-image'),
    isPlaceholder: true
  }
];
```

Then when a user adds their own image, I would set `isPlaceholder: false`.

Any thoughts on a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly on `iOS`. Regarding `Android`, I can't validate yet.

```
import * as SQLite from "expo-sqlite";

const DB_NAME = SQLite.openDatabase("yourDbName.db");
export const insertXYZ = (
  imageUrl,
) => {
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    DB_NAME.transaction((SQLiteTransaction) => {
      SQLiteTransaction.executeSql(
        `INSERT INTO yourDbName (imageUrl) VALUES (?);`,
        [imageUrl],
        (transaction, result) => {
          resolve(result);
        },
        (transaction, error) => {
          reject(error);
        }
      );
    });
  });

  return promise;
};
```